# Avalondock - Delayed layout restore for some panels

Tags: c#, mvvm, avalondock

I'm using Load/Save layout similar way described on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/719143/avalondock-tutorial-part-load-save-layout). Catching LayoutSerializationCallback event and trying to find the corresponding viewModel for LayoutItem

```
private void LayoutSerializer_LayoutSerializationCallback(object sender, LayoutSerializationCallbackEventArgs e)
        {
            // This can happen if the previous session was loading a file
            // but was unable to initialize the view ...
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Model.ContentId) || (e.Content = ReloadItem(e.Model)) == null)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }

private object ReloadItem(object item)
{
    object ret = null;

    switch (item)
    {
        case LayoutAnchorable anchorable:
            //list of tools windows
            ret = Manager.Tools.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ContentId == anchorable.ContentId);
            if(ret == null && anchorable.ContentId.StartsWith(MapPanel.MapPanelPrefix))
            {

                MapPanels.Add(anchorable);
            }
            break;
        case LayoutDocument document:
            // list of restored documents
            ret = Manager.Documents.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ContentId == document.ContentId);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented type of AD item ");
    }

    return ret;

}
```

This works fine when I have all ViewModels available when deserializing/restoring layout.

But I'm thinking about something like delayed layout restore. In my case, I have some documents and some panels available at the start. But there can be some panels (call them MapPanel) that are loaded later (viewModels are loaded somewhere in future). And I can't figure out, how to restore layout for these panels.

For this case, I have List MapPanels to store anchorable that are loaded at avalondock layout load and trying to restore them in BeforeInsertAnchorable in ILayoutUpdateStrategy. But when I debug it, stored LayoutAnchorable has different parents that stored one. So I assume that after canceling (e.Cancel = true) in LayoutSerializationCallback somehow modifies not restored anchorable.

```
public bool BeforeInsertAnchorable(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutAnchorable anchorableToShow, ILayoutContainer destinationContainer)
        {
            if (anchorableToShow.Content is ToolPanel tool)
            {

                if(tool is MapPanel)
                {
                    anchorableToShow = LayoutSaveLoadUtil.Instance.MapPanels.FirstOrDefault(mp => mp.ContentId == anchorableToShow.ContentId);
                }

                var destPane = destinationContainer as LayoutAnchorablePane;
                if (destinationContainer != null && destinationContainer.FindParent<LayoutFloatingWindow>() != null)
                    return false;


                var dockLeftPane = layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutAnchorablePane>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == tool.PreferredLocation + "Pane");
                if (dockLeftPane != null)
                {
                    dockLeftPane.Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            return false;

        }
```

So I'm curious what is the right approach to achieve this. I was also thinking about restoring layout (again) after MapPanel is loaded, but I don't know how to skip all other LayoutItems. So is there any possibility of how to restore a single Anchorable position, floating parent, docking, size, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i probably figured out solution.

I have some panels (call them MapPanel) and theyr content isnt loaded when layout is restored from XML. In my case i have app, that has some documents and tabs, and in aditional, user can load aditional data to show maps.

And i needed to restore layout of this maps when user load them. (click button, selec where to load maps etc)

I have static class called LayoutSaveLoadUtil (as described on codeproject) when i have aditional list MapPanelsStorage of type LayoutAnchorable. To this list i store all layouts that missing content on layout restore and ContentId has specific prefix. This tells me that is MapPanel. Then i create a dummy content, assign it to this panel and set its visibility to false (so panel is invisible)

(this is called in layoutSerializationCallback)

```
private object ReloadItem(object item)
{
    object ret = null;

    switch (item)
    {
        case LayoutAnchorable anchorable:
            //list of tools windows
            ret = Manager.Tools.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ContentId == anchorable.ContentId);
            if(ret == null && anchorable.ContentId.StartsWith(MapPanel.MapPanelPrefix))
            {
                //when layoutAnchorable is MapPanel (has MapPanel prefix) and its content is loaded yet
                //store its layout into list to restore it later (when content is loaded)
                MapPanelsStorage.Add(anchorable);
                //Set anchorable visibility to false 
                anchorable.IsVisible = false;
                //return dummy model for avalondock layout serialization
                ret = new EmptyMapViewModel();
            }
            break;
        case LayoutDocument document:
            // list of restored documents
            ret = Manager.Documents.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ContentId == document.ContentId);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented type of AD item ");
    }

    return ret;

}
```

Then in BeforeInsertAnchorable (called when new panel is added into layout) i check if panel content is MapPanel, look for stored layout, try to find parent (LayoutAnchorablePane/LayoutDocumentPane) and then add it instead of DummyHidden panel, and just remove it from storage.

```
//hacky hacky to restore map panel layout when map is opened after layout is loaded
//in layout deserialization, deserialize layout for MapPanels that hasnt DataModels yet with DummyModel to preserve their layout
if (anchorableToShow.Content is MapPanel mappanel)
{
    var storedMapsLayout = LayoutSaveLoadUtil.Instance.MapPanelsStorage;

    //check if Map panel has stored layout from previous layout deserialization
    var matchingAnchorable = storedMapsLayout.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ContentId == mappanel.ContentId);
    if (matchingAnchorable != null)
    {
        //make preserved layout visible, so its parent and etc is restored. Without this, correct parent LayoutGroup isnt found
        matchingAnchorable.IsVisible = true;

        LayoutAnchorablePane matchingAnchorablePane;
        LayoutDocumentPane matchingDocumentPane;

        //find parent layoutGroup. This can be LayoutAnchorablePane or LayoutDocumentPane
        if ((matchingAnchorablePane = matchingAnchorable.FindParent<LayoutAnchorablePane>()) != null)
        {
            //add new panel into layoutGroup with correct layout
            matchingAnchorablePane.Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
            //remove old dummy panel
            matchingAnchorablePane.RemoveChild(matchingAnchorable);
            //remove restored layout from storage
            storedMapsLayout.Remove(matchingAnchorable);
            return true;
        }
        else if ((matchingDocumentPane = matchingAnchorable.FindParent<LayoutDocumentPane>()) != null)
        {
            //add new panel into layoutGroup with correct layout
            matchingDocumentPane.Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
            //remove old dummy panel
            matchingDocumentPane.RemoveChild(matchingAnchorable);
            //remove restored layout from storage
            storedMapsLayout.Remove(matchingAnchorable);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            matchingAnchorable.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
}
```